# SceneKit SCNTransformConstraint

Tags: ios8, scenekit

I am trying to apply some position constraints to a very simple scene. What I would like to do is have an initial node, then use a constraint to position a second node relative to the first. Then position a third node relative to the second etc. I realise I can nest the nodes but that is not what I ultimately want. Moving the first node would move all 3. What I have noticed having applied a constraint to the the second node is that the position is still 0,0,0 even though the constraint has positioned my node correctly. This has a knock on effect to the third node as the position of the second node is 0,0,0 therefore the third node is positioned relative to the first... I hope this makes sense? :-s

I have also noticed this effects the getBoundingBoxMin of the entire scene, as I need to establish the dimensions of the entire scene.

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible with constraints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints are applied at render time, so it won't change your model (i.e it won't modify the positions of your nodes in your model tree).
That said you can retrieve the presentation positions of your nodes like this:

node.presentationNode.position

Comment: Thanks Toyos, I didn't realise that the constraints didn't modify the scene. Using the presentationNode works as expected.